# How to make a text file (name1:hobby1 name2:hobby2) into this (name1:hobby1, hobby2 name2:hobby1, hobby2)?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I need some help. I have a text file with lots of names and hobbies that looks something like this:

> Jack:crafting
>
> Peter:hiking
>
> Wendy:gaming
>
> Monica:tennis
>
> Chris:origami
>
> Sophie:sport
>
> Monica:design

Some of the names and hobbies are repeated. I'm trying to make the program display something like this:

> Jack: crafting, movies, yoga
>
> Wendy: gaming, hiking, sport

This is my program so far, but the 4 lines from the end are incorrect.

```
def create_dictionary(file):
newlist = []
dict = {}
file = open("hobbies_database.txt", "r")
hobbies = file.readlines()
for rows in hobbies:
    rows1 = rows.split(":")
    k = rows1[0] # nimi
    v = (rows1[1]).rstrip("\n") # hobi
    dict = {k: v}
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if v in dict[k]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
import sys 
from collections import defaultdict


def create_dictionary(inputfile):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in inputfile:
        name, hobby = line.split(':', 1)
        d[name].append(hobby.strip())
    return d


with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp: 
    for name, hobbies in create_dictionary(fp).items():
        print(name, ': ', sep='', end='')
        print(*hobbies, sep=', ')
```

Your example give me this result:

```
Sophie: sport
Chris: origami
Peter: hiking
Jack: crafting
Wendy: gaming
Monica: tennis, design
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this. I've deliberately rewritten this as I'm trying to show you how you would go about this in a more "Pythonic way". At least making use of the language a bit more.

For example, you can create arrays within dictionaries to represent the data more intuitively. It will then be easier to print the information out in the way you want.

```
def create_dictionary(file):

    names = {} # create the dictionary to store your data

    # using with statement ensures the file is closed properly
    # even if there is an error thrown
    with open("hobbies_database.txt", "r") as file:

        # This reads the file one line at a time
        # using readlines() loads the whole file into memory in one go
        # This is far better for large data files that wont fit into memory
        for row in file:

            # strip() removes end of line characters and trailing white space
            # split returns an array [] which can be unpacked direct to single variables
            name, hobby = row.strip().split(":")

            # this checks to see if 'name' has been seen before
            # is there already an entry in the dictionary
            if name not in names:

                # if not, assign an empty array to the dictionary key 'name'
                names[name] = []

            # this adds the hobby seen in this line to the array
            names[name].append(hobby)

    # This iterates through all the keys in the dictionary
    for name in names:

        # using the string format function you can build up
        # the output string and print it to the screen

        # ",".join(array) will join all the elements of the array
        # into a single string and place a comma between each

        # set(array) creates a "list/array" of unique objects
        # this means that if a hobby is added twice you will only see it once in the set

        # names[name] is the list [] of hobby strings for that 'name'
        print("{0}: {1}\n".format(name, ", ".join(set(names[name]))))
```

Hope this helps, and perhaps points you in the direction of a few more Python concepts. If you haven't been through the introductory tutorial yet... i'd definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

you may try this one

```
data = map(lambda x:x.strip(), open('hobbies_database.txt'))
tmp = {}
for i in data:
    k,v = i.strip().split(':')
    if not tmp.get(k, []):
        tmp[k] = []
    tmp[k].append(v)
for k,v in tmp.iteritems():
    print k, ':', ','.join(v)
```

output:

```
Monica : tennis,design
Jack : crafting
Wendy : gaming
Chris : origami
Sophie : sport
Peter : hiking
```